# Retag questions in the 'django' tag with 'python' as well?

Tags: discussion, tags

Occasionally I find some 'django' questions, where I consider adding a 'python' tag, because:

- Django is written in Python,
- by using a little broader (but still valid) tag, more people may take a look at the question (and it gets resolved faster, probably)

*Is there any guideline for such cases?*

(Similarly 'ruby-on-rails' is written in 'ruby', but only a few 'ruby-on-rails' questions are tagged 'ruby'. Note: Currently I don't retag questions, where someone asks for specific framework related things; if the question is more open, I used to add the more general tag, e.g. 'python'.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most questions tagged [django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django) are usually about very specific Django related issues where general Python knowledge won't help. For example, the five newest questions currently are:

- [Database choice choice for Django project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4774653/database-choice-choice-for-django-project)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4774489/eclipse-formatter-django-template-tags
- [Avoiding circular dependencies in Django applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4774344/avoiding-circular-dependencies-in-django-applications)
- [How to use startproject (django-admin.py) if there is already a django project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4774128/how-to-use-startproject-django-admin-py-if-there-is-already-a-django-project)
- [Keeping track of how many views an object receives in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4773694/keeping-track-of-how-many-views-an-object-receives-in-django)

I think none of those are of interest for someone who doesn't know Django but only plain Python. Also nobody without special Django knowledge will be able to answer them. Therefore I don't think those questions should be tagged [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python), they are all about the Django framework and would be the same if Django was written in some other language.

Of course there are exceptions where somebody really has a Python question and it just happens to arise in the context of a Django app. These of course should be tagged [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) then. But I don't think a general rule that [django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django) should always come with [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) would be useful.

Comment: Thank you; this reflects mainly my approach. Just wondered, if there was some canonical approach to this beside (the hopefully sane) common sense.

Comment: Should we then *remove* `[python]` if it looks very django-specific (considering questions with the tag of course)?

Comment: Yes.. I think it wise to remove [python] in that case.  If django was written in Java would the question still apply?  Yes?  Remove [python].